# C# one letter on each row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

I have a gridview, a textbox and a button. When a value is entered in the textbox and the button is pressed, that value should be sent to the gridview. Everything went well so far, the gridview is created when I enter a value. HOWEVER, the value enetered appears on letter per row. So if the value is 'car' it appears as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzCko.jpg).

Here is my code:

```
protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
    GridView1.DataSource = TextBox1.Text;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CaptionAlign="Left" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="242px" >
<EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: That will happen if you bind directly to a string, yes. Why not binding to the `DataTable` you just created instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to assign data table `dt` to DataSource instead of `TextBox1.Text`

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: god bless you that was it

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes:

```
protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What exactly does dt.AcceptChanges() do?

Comment: Commits all the changes made to this table.